# local minimum IN A MATLAB PLOT

Tags: matlab, local, minimum

I want to recognize a local minimum in my data in a [plot figure in Matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEq5z.jpg)

Comment: do you have access to the image processing toolbox?

Comment: Please include the image in the question instead of linking to it. Also, what you call _main minimum_ is usually called _global minimum_. It is not clear if you are asking about the algorithm to use or the actual code to implement it. In both cases, you should prove that you have already done your homework yourself (e.g. by providing some code you’ve already unsuccessfully tried). SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

From your description I assume that you actually have the data already digitalized, and doing image processing to get from your drawing to digital data is not part of the problem. Please try to be much more specific and complete with your questions in the future :).

Basically, you just want to smooth out your data first. The following quick-and-dirty code should get you really close to what you need.

```
x = 0:0.1:10;
y = 3*sin(x) + rand(size(x));
y_filtered = smooth(y);
figure

[min, idx] = findpeaks(-y_filtered); %findpeaks finds maxima, so invert it

hold on
plot(x,y)
plot(x,y_filtered)
plot(x(idx),y_filtered(idx),'bo')
```

Try playing around with the parameters of `smooth()`, or do your own filtering (i.e. with a Fourier transform or whatnot).

Comment: but my dataset is very big and i am ploting 1000000 samples in a figure , and smoothing data is not very effective on my data and plot.

Comment: i am trying to send a new image but i dont know how to send it

Comment: can i have your email address, please?

Comment: Simply edit your original question; this way more people can possibly help you, also your question can hep other people who potentially have the same question.